# Passportjs BearerStrategy vs. OAuth2Strategy

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm trying to make a oauth2 client against a custom oauth2 provider using passportjs to authenticate. There's 2 strategy in passportjs that stands out, BearerStrategy and OAuth2Strategy. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OAuth2Strategy` is the one to use if you are an OAuth 2.0 client, authenticating against a third party provider, which sounds like your situation.

`BearerStrategy` is used if you are an OAuth 2.0 provider, and are authenticating tokens you previously issued to clients.

Comment: May I humbly suggest adding this to the READMEs for each of these two projects? I am relatively new to OAuth in node.js, and this confused me for some time. Thanks for the clear answer here!